# Reorder HTML table rows using drag-and-drop

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function to move table rows up and down. I do not know how to save the data, nor get the position of each row. I am using PHP to show the table rows.

How do I get each table row position value when the user reorders the table rows?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The jQuery UI [sortable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) provides drag-and-drop reordering. A save button can extract the IDs of each item to create a comma-delimited string of those IDs, added to a hidden textbox. The textbox is returned to the server using an async postback.

This [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pmw57/tzYbU/205/) reorders table elements, but does not save them to a database.

The sortable plugin takes one line of code to turn any list into a sortable list. If you care to use them, it also provides CSS and images to provide a visual impact to sortable list (see the example that I linked to). Developers, however, must provide code to retrieve items in their new order. I embed unique IDs of each item in the list as an HTML attribute and then retrieve those IDs via jQuery.

For example:

```
// ----- code executed when the document loads
$(function() {
    wireReorderList();
});

function wireReorderList() {
    $("#reorderExampleItems").sortable();
    $("#reorderExampleItems").disableSelection();
}

function saveOrderClick() {
    // ----- Retrieve the li items inside our sortable list
    var items = $("#reorderExampleItems li");

    var linkIDs = [items.size()];
    var index = 0;

    // ----- Iterate through each li, extracting the ID embedded as an attribute
    items.each(
        function(intIndex) {
            linkIDs[index] = $(this).attr("ExampleItemID");
            index++;
        });

    $get("<%=txtExampleItemsOrder.ClientID %>").value = linkIDs.join(",");
}
```

Comment: If you examine my example more closely, the code is independent of how you actually go about sorting it(in your case simply query for tr instead of li to get your rows). You can retrieve any value you want from your list by storing it as an html attribute and then using jquery attr() to retrieve the values, in sorted order. 


I will further add that I do not appreicate your tone at all. I provided the answer you were asking for and recommended you look at a very popular method of doing the sorting in case you were not aware of it.

Comment: Your line `var linkIDs = [items.size()];` is NOT initializing an array of size `items.size()`. You are simply creating an array with a single element containing that size. Which gets overwritten in the items.each's first iteration..

Comment: Jim, How can i save this array in a DataBase MySQL? do you know where have a tutorial about it?

Comment: Works awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Apparently the question poorly describes the OP's problem, but this question is the top search result for dragging to reorder table rows, so that is what I will answer. I wasn't interested in bringing in jQuery UI for something so simple, so here is a jQuery only solution:

```js
$(".grab").mousedown(function(e) {
  var tr = $(e.target).closest("TR"),
    si = tr.index(),
    sy = e.pageY,
    b = $(document.body),
    drag;
  if (si == 0) return;
  b.addClass("grabCursor").css("userSelect", "none");
  tr.addClass("grabbed");

  function move(e) {
    if (!drag && Math.abs(e.pageY - sy) < 10) return;
    drag = true;
    tr.siblings().each(function() {
      var s = $(this),
        i = s.index(),
        y = s.offset().top;
      if (i > 0 && e.pageY >= y && e.pageY < y + s.outerHeight()) {
        if (i < tr.index())
          tr.insertAfter(s);
        else
          tr.insertBefore(s);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  function up(e) {
    if (drag && si != tr.index()) {
      drag = false;
      alert("moved!");
    }
    $(document).unbind("mousemove", move).unbind("mouseup", up);
    b.removeClass("grabCursor").css("userSelect", "none");
    tr.removeClass("grabbed");
  }
  $(document).mousemove(move).mouseup(up);
});
```

```css
.grab {
  cursor: grab;
}

.grabbed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 13px #000;
}

.grabCursor,
.grabCursor * {
  cursor: grabbing !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Table Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="grab">&#9776;</td>
    <td>Table Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="grab">&#9776;</td>
    <td>Table Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="grab">&#9776;</td>
    <td>Table Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note `si == 0` and `i > 0` ignores the first row, which for me contains `TH` tags. Replace the `alert` with your "drag finished" logic.

Comment: Great work man. This made my day. Here is my fiddle if anyone finds it useful. https://jsfiddle.net/7ko9ay1e/

Comment: How can we do it for multiple rows

Answer (score 7):

I working well with it

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#catalog tbody tr").draggable({
            appendTo:"body",
            helper:"clone"
        });
        $("#cart tbody").droppable({
            activeClass:"ui-state-default",
            hoverClass:"ui-state-hover",
            accept:":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop:function (event, ui) {
                $('.placeholder').remove();
                row = ui.draggable;
                $(this).append(row);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Easy for plugin jquery TableDnd

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Initialise the first table (as before)
    $("#table-1").tableDnD();

    // Make a nice striped effect on the table
    $("#table-2 tr:even').addClass('alt')");

    // Initialise the second table specifying a dragClass and an onDrop function that will display an alert
    $("#table-2").tableDnD({
        onDragClass: "myDragClass",
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
            var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
            var debugStr = "Row dropped was "+row.id+". New order: ";
            for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
                debugStr += rows[i].id+" ";
            }
            $(table).parent().find('.result').text(debugStr);
        },
        onDragStart: function(table, row) {
            $(table).parent().find('.result').text("Started dragging row "+row.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Plugin (TableDnD):
https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/DenisHo/dxpLrcd9/embedded/result/

CDN:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.tablednd/0.8/jquery.tablednd.0.8.min.js

Comment: Hi Is it possible to use this plugin with JSF as well?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [jQuery Sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable). I used it to reorder table rows.

Comment: thanks but did u even read my question ?! im not looking for a new d&d plugin . just wondering how to solve my current script's problem in fetching  each row value

Comment: @Ghazanfari, I can't see any script in your question that anyone can solve.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the fiddle from @tim, this version tightens the scope and formatting, and converts `bind()` -> `on()`. It's designed to bind on a dedicated `td` as the handle instead of the entire row. In my use case, I have `input` fields so the "drag anywhere on the row" approach felt confusing.

Tested working on desktop. Only partial success with mobile touch. Can't get it to run correctly on SO's runnable snippet for some reason...

```js
let ns = {
  drag: (e) => {
    let el = $(e.target),
      d = $('body'),
      tr = el.closest('tr'),
      sy = e.pageY,
      drag = false,
      index = tr.index();

    tr.addClass('grabbed');

    function move(e) {
      if (!drag && Math.abs(e.pageY - sy) < 10)
        return;
      drag = true;
      tr.siblings().each(function() {
        let s = $(this),
          i = s.index(),
          y = s.offset().top;
        if (e.pageY >= y && e.pageY < y + s.outerHeight()) {
          i < tr.index() ? s.insertAfter(tr) : s.insertBefore(tr);
          return false;
        }
      });
    }

    function up(e) {
      if (drag && index !== tr.index())
        drag = false;

      d.off('mousemove', move).off('mouseup', up);
      //d.off('touchmove', move).off('touchend', up); //failed attempt at touch compatibility
      tr.removeClass('grabbed');
    }
    d.on('mousemove', move).on('mouseup', up);
    //d.on('touchmove', move).on('touchend', up);
  }
};

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('body').on('mousedown touchstart', '.drag', ns.drag);
});
```

```css
.grab {
  cursor: grab;
  user-select: none
}

tr.grabbed {
  box-shadow: 4px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

tr.grabbed:active {
  user-input: none;
}

tr.grabbed:active * {
  user-input: none;
  cursor: grabbing !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Drag the rows below...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='grab'>&vellip;</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Row 1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='grab'>&vellip;</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Row 2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='grab'>&vellip;</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Row 3" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```