# How to prevent Bootstrap from making the dragged row change in width?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop

I would like to have a table which allows me to drag and drop to reorder its rows in it.

Here is the solution offered by Trevor and the original author.

[A table and its rows gets changed in width when dragging and dropping to reorder its rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068789/a-table-and-its-rows-gets-changed-in-width-when-dragging-and-dropping-to-reorder)

Here is the jsfiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/2Sg8v/

However, if I add Bootstrap class "table" to the table, the dragged row shrinks. I tried many ways to set the width of the dragged row (the row dynamically created by JQuery UI) and got no success.  Here is the jsfiddle demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/8sRxL/1/

Here is the only change (the table class) after adding Bootstrap css.

```
<table id="sort" class="grid table" title="Kurt Vonnegut novels">
```

Any way to fix this?

Though the post's title mentions Bootstrap, it may be just caused by 100% table width. However, I need to have 100% for the table width because of the design that I have no control.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

When setting the widths I find that if you add an extra 16-18 pixels to each column that evens it out so that it does not shrink.

```
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width()+17); // 16 - 18
    });
```

See Example

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/G3D8T/1/)

Comment: Trevor, thanks again for helping me on this. I tested your fiddle demo and the row shrinks when I drag it. I am using Chrome.

Comment: @curious1 hmm I am using chrome as well and I am not seeing the same behavior.. Could you share a screenshot of what your seeing?  Maybe I am not understanding the issue correctly.

Comment: I updated the post with the screenshot. You can see the dragged row "Player Piano" shrinks.

Comment: @curious1 thanks for the screenshot.  Take a look at my update.

Comment: Trevor, thanks so much for making it work. I noticed that you added hard-coded values such as in $(this).css('margin-left','15px'); Are these values applied to any tables or just the table in your jsFiddle demo? Put it another way, in what circumstances, the script works correctly? Thanks!!!

Comment: @curious1 sorry that `margin-left:15px` is not actually needed I forgot to remove that from my fiddle.  as far the the `width()+17` yes its hard coded but that seems to help the row not shrink.  I tested a number of cases by making the screen larger and smaller and It did not seem to affect it.  So at least with my initial testing I'm not seeing that the hard coded value interferes with anything.  Check my update I removed unneeded code.

Comment: Trevor, with your update, the row in my actual problem still shrinks, but a little. Good for now. Can I buy you a cup of coffee? Thanks!!!

Comment: Trevor, I would like to share a finding with you. I measured the width of TDs of the table. The I actual width I got from the scree is larger  than what JQuery got such as $originals.eq(index).width(). I cannot explain why. I use what I got from the screen measurement to set the width of the helper. I got perfect dragged row. This is strange.

Comment: @curious1 wow, that is strange.  I don't can't think of why that would be the case.