# How to drag and drop rows with database update in ASP.NET Core using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using this jQuery UI Library to drag and drop rows of a table in an ASP.NET Core MVC application.

script.js

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#SortTable")
    .sortable({ items: "tr.sortable" })
    .dragtable({dragHandle: ".dragHandle"})
    .tablesorter();
})
```

cshtml

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" id="SortTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><div class="dragHandle"></div>A</th>
                <th><div class="dragHandle"></div>B</th>
                <th><div class="dragHandle"></div>C</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var ticket in Model)
            {
                <tr class="sortable">
                    <td>@ticket.A</td>
                    <td>@ticket.B</td>
                    <td>@(ticket.C + "(" + ticket.abc + ")")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I send request to the controller and update the changes in the database?

Comment: Could you pls offer the plugin's url, I mean the tutorial of using this dragging plugin.

Comment: Here is the tutorial that I found for the drag and drop feature: https://embed.plnkr.co/twDXmS/ @TinyWang

Comment: `update the changes` means change the order of the data? I'm not sure which kind of data should be update

Comment: Updating the changes of the display order. 
For example: CurrentDisplayOrder={1,2,3,4,5}
ChangedDisplayOrder={2,3,1,5,4}

I want to show the data as per the changed display order only listed as 1,2,3,4,5
But the real order is 2,3,1,5,4
@TinyWang

Comment: Therefore, we need to combine each row and its order, then send it to the database?

Comment: My final goal is to achieve this: https://giphy.com/gifs/UONEJlrPe46qGZ1jgy @TinyWang
I am using EntityFramework in the backend and mssql database.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is push the new order along the row id into an array and send the array to backend and then in your backend you can update your database. I also refer to this [high vote answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072938) to achieve the reset order feature.

Try my code below:

My controller:

```
public IActionResult Tickets()
{
    List<TicketModel> list = new List<TicketModel>
    {
        new TicketModel{ rowid="aa", A="11",B="12",C="13",abc="hello"},
        new TicketModel{ rowid="bb", A="21",B="22",C="23",abc="world"},
        new TicketModel{ rowid="cc", A="31",B="32",C="33",abc="!!"}
    };
    return View(list);
}
[HttpPost]
public string resetOrder([FromBody] List<TicketModel> postData) {
    return "success";
}
```

My cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppMvc.Models.TicketModel>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><div class="dragHandle"></div>A</th>
                <th><div class="dragHandle"></div>B</th>
                <th><div class="dragHandle"></div>C</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{int i = 1;}
            @foreach (var ticket in Model)
            {
            <tr class="sortable">
                <td class="index" id="@ticket.rowid">@i</td>
                @{i++;}
                <td>@ticket.A</td>
                <td>@ticket.B</td>
                <td>@(ticket.C + "(" + ticket.abc + ")")</td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="updateBtn">update</button>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/js/jquery.ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.dragtable.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var reslist = [];
            var fixHelperModified = function (e, tr) {
                var $originals = tr.children();
                var $helper = tr.clone();
                $helper.children().each(function (index) {
                    $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
                });
                return $helper;
            },
                updateIndex = function (e, ui) {
                    $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
                        //$(this).html(i + 1);
                        var data = new Object();
                        data.rowid = $(this).attr("id");
                        data.order = (i + 1).toString();
                        reslist.push(data);
                        console.info(reslist);
                    });

                    
                };
            $("#myTable")
                .sortable({
                    items: "tr.sortable",
                    helper: fixHelperModified,
                    stop: updateIndex
                })
                .dragtable({ dragHandle: ".dragHandle" })
                .tablesorter();
        });
        $('#updateBtn').click(function(){
           $.ajax({
                        url: "/home/resetOrder",
                        data: JSON.stringify(reslist),
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            reslist = [];
                        }
                    });
        });
    </script>
}
```

My model:

```
public class TicketModel
    {
        public string rowid { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string abc { get; set; }
        public string order { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/UONEJlrPe46qGZ1jgy @TinyWang

Comment: therefore, just comment the line-code of `$(this).html(i + 1);` to make it not change the index. Then you can move the ajax request to the button on click event so that the update will triggered when the button is clicked. Then in your backend, you got the data, you used EF core to update the database is not influenced by this changing.

Answer (score 0):

"Reordering rows at database level" is always a tricky thing to do. The **Stern-Brocot** technique was designed to enable reordering of items while only having to update a single row in the database.

### Stern-brocot

The theory is basically that when using fractions, adding together the numerators and adding together the denominators will result in a new fraction which is always in between the other two:

```
   1 /    1 = 1
   2 /    1 = 2

Now were dragging one in between

   1 /    1 = 1
   3 /    2 = 1.5
   2 /    1 = 2

Now were adding yet another one in between

   1 /    1 = 1
   4 /    3 = 1.333
   3 /    2 = 1.5
   2 /    1 = 2

Now put another between the second and the third

   1 /    1 = 1
   5 /    4 = 1.25
   4 /    3 = 1.333
   3 /    2 = 1.5
   2 /    1 = 2
```

This is all working fine in theory. The numbers don't skyrocket as fast as other techniques, and the values can be stored easily.

However I did make a [proof-of-concept](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/DragDropOrderingDatabase) some time ago, and this clearly shows the limitations of the Stern-brocot technique.

While the numbers can be persisted with 100% accuracy, database servers only do number computations to a certain "precision" (if you're using doubles with a mantissa and exponent). The demo clearly shows that when you start off with 10 items to be reordered, you can already lose precision after a mere 47 moves (if you try your best).

### Atlassian

Atlassian has a blog post on how they deal with reordering items effectively. However atm. I'm not able to find it.