# How to change the position of an item in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a simple table like this one:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>id</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to drag and drop an item from a position to another and change the number of that item to the number of the item it was replaced with but the name and id wouldn't change. for example in the table above I drag blue to the first spot hence the number of blue becomes 1 but blue's id remains 2, and the number of red becomes 2 but red's id remains 1 and their positions in the table also change.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder HTML table rows using drag-and-drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072848/reorder-html-table-rows-using-drag-and-drop)

Comment: @angel.bonev I thought I could use javascript to grab the value of the selected item's name and id and also grab the value of the item we want to replace with and replace their values but I'm not sure if it works or not and I don't know how to make the drag and drop effect

Comment: Try it you will learn alot more if you do it your self first and then post what was you attepts. Just search for `drag and drop javascript table` and you will see how many articles and different aprouches you will find

Comment: @angel.bonev it does but I want a solution that doesn't use a library or framework and is only with javascript itself

Comment: @angel.bonev ok then I'll try to work on my own and I'll update the post once I got any new results

Comment: there are 2 problems you have to solve. First, you have to make a table row draggable. There are plenty of tutorials even for vanilla Javascript such [as this one](https://web.dev/drag-and-drop/?gclid=CjwKCAjwq5-WBhB7EiwAl-HEkudFcB_pnDrsc4LRU00KIFacGEuoPjv0-vrm-C8yfJ_iUhFDGuQbaBoCNmYQAvD_BwE). Second you need to re-order the id and number which would be the easiest way to solve with a simple `for`-loop.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for the first tutorial but can you please give more details on the second part with the re ordering?

Comment: well, do you know what a `for`-loop is?

Comment: @tacoshy um yeah it was the first thing I learned in loops

Comment: Then you know how to count all the elements and raise and index. All you need to do now is to include the index as innerHTML or textContent...

Comment: @tacoshy ah I got it now. thanks for the help :D

Comment: @AnotherRandomUser next time just try something your self first. Self learning is  very important. We'll be glad to help when there is any problems. Cheers

Comment: @angel.bonev yes I should have tried first but I was kind of unsure if my idea worked or no. I'll try to focus more on practicing first and asking afterwards next time. and thanks a lot for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [drag event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event), when you *start draging* it make a copy of `target` you will need it when *draging over*.

After the drag ends just reorder the first **td** in every  table row (**tr**) excluding any row in **thead** by selecting **tbody**

```js
let shadow
function dragit(event) {
    shadow = event.target;
}
function dragover(e) {
    let children = Array.from(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children);
    if (children.indexOf(e.target.parentNode) > children.indexOf(shadow))
        e.target.parentNode.after(shadow);
    else
        e.target.parentNode.before(shadow);
}
function reOrder() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".myTable > tbody > tr > td:first-child").forEach(function (elem, index) {
        elem.innerHTML = (index + 1);
    });
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
 <table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr draggable="true"  ondragstart="dragit(event)"  ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragend="reOrder()">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true"  ondragstart="dragit(event)"  ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragend="reOrder()">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true"  ondragstart="dragit(event)"  ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragend="reOrder()">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>yellow</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```